# CSS id selector for <a> element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am new to HTML/CSS. I tried to select an  element using an id selector but my CSS code does not work.  Can someone explain why it does not work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #bigButton a {text-decoration:none;color:green;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>test</p>
<a id=”bigButton” href=”page1.html”>Click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that I also tried the CSS without a  (i.e. `#bigButton {text-decoration:none;color:green;}` ) but this did not work either.

Comment: There's also the fact that you have fancy quotes instead of straight quotes for some reason.

Comment: @BoltClock is right that the fancy quotes were part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `a` to perform the *id selector*  it is just:

```css
#bigButton {text-decoration:none;color:green;}
```

---

This would work:

```css
 #bigButton a {text-decoration:none;color:green;}
```

---

if you had a parent element like this for `a`:

```
<div id="bigButton">
<a  href="page1.html">Click here</a>
</div>
```

And also as pointed out by @Pilot and @BoltClock quotes selection may be another reason try something like this instead `"` or `id="bigButton"`

**[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Twa3/)**

Comment: If you want more specificity, you can always use `a#bigButton`, which also works.

Answer (score 2):

```css
a#bigButton {text-decoration:none;color:green;}
```

---

Your CSS

```css
#bigButton a {text-decoration:none;color:green;}
```

meant "any `a` elements with an ancestor whose id is `bigButton`".